# Ajax e dataType JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Quando faço assim, o retorno é um parsererror.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "servicos.php",
    data: "id=1",
    dataType: 'json', ==========================> Essa linha bem aqui
    success: function(retorno,status){
    // retorno = JSON.parse(retorno);

    $("#tudo").html(retorno);
},
error: function(retorno,erro){

    $("#tudo").html(retorno.responseText);

}
});
```

Só dá success se remover essa linha ou deixar como 'text'.

Porém (ainda deixando dataType: 'json'), quando peço para retornar o erro desta fomra:

```
error: function(retorno,erro){

    $("#tudo").html(retorno.responseText);

}
```

Recebo o mesmo resultado do success sem o "dataType: 'json'"

Não entendi isso.

Comment: O que esse PHP está retornando? Tem certeza de que é um JSON válido?

Comment: Outra coisa é que o jQuery tenta parsear o json sozinho, mesmo sem declarar o datatype. Então pode ser simplesmente isso, o argumento retorno já é um objeto, pode usar direto do seu callback.

Comment: o retorno é algo assim:
[{"id":"1","nome":"juca","status":"1"}]

Comment: Amigo eu testei aqui e funcionou,apenas trocando o dataType por datatype

Answer (score 1):

Se, simplesmente, copiar e colar sua requisição *ajax*, em tese, vai funcionar. Mas deve considerar o seguinte: notei que seu arquivo **servicos.php** retorna uma matriz de objetos:

> o retorno é algo assim: [{"id":"1","nome":"juca","status":"1"}]

Logo, quando você "recebe" a matriz/*array* (no `success`), deve exibir a resposta assim:

```
$("#tudo").html(retorno[0].nome);
```

`retorno[0]` vai referenciar o primeiro objeto na matriz/*array* retornada na requisição;

`.nome` vai referenciar o atributo `nome` no objeto retornado;

Veja a diferença na utilização:

```
// Quando o json retornado é array: [{"id":1, "nome":"juca", ...}]
$("#tudo").html(retorno[0].nome);

// Quando o json retornado é objeto: {"id":1, "nome":"juca", ...}
$("#tudo").html(retorno.nome);
```

Normalmente, utiliza-se matriz/*array* quando recebe mais de um objeto:

```
json = JSON.parse('[{"id":0,"nome":"jao","status":1},{"id":1,"nome":"juca","status":1},{"id":2,"nome":"ze","status":0}]');

console.log(json[0].nome);  //jao
console.log(json[1].nome);  //juca
console.log(json[2].nome);  //ze
```

Nos meus testes utilizei *jQuery 1.12.4*.

Subi um projeto baseado nessa resposta no meu [GitHub/LipESprY/sopt-ajax-e-datatype-json](https://github.com/lipespry/sopt-ajax-e-datatype-json)